# how to save workbook into a txt file using a button click

Tags: excel, vba

there is a need to save the workbooks in a spreadsheet into seperate txt files on my location.

but the code which i am using in the button click is ertreiving the data to the desired location and the files include special characters which iam not interested in.

can any one help me in getting the txt file as i get the details in the print preview screen.

code used:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim xlApp As Object
  Dim xlBook As Object
  Dim xlSheet As Object
  Dim strOutputFileName
  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\bera02a\Desktop\Arun_TAT_Testing_orig_14022013.xls")
  For Each xlSheet In xlBook.Worksheets
    strOutputFileName = "C:\Documents and Settings\bera02a\Desktop\" & xlSheet.Name & ".txt"
    xlSheet.SaveAs strOutputFileName
  Next
  xlApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Please specify / provide example of these special chars you're not interested in having in the output?

Comment: This is the extract of the ouput that is coming in the text file saved.

Comment: This is the extract of the ouput that is coming in the text file saved.

ÐÏà¡±á                >  þÿ                          $     þÿÿÿ        b   ã   p  ç  h

Comment: My file contains some commans and ) symbols but not the above stated.While checking in print preview of the workbook i am getting the output.but when it is saving i couldnt get.Help needed urgently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the cause of your incorrect output is NOT specifying the desired saving format. Try to replace your saving line of code with this:

```
xlSheet.SaveAs Filename:=strOutputFileName, FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText
```

This will define out put as Unicode text file - I suppose that's what you want.

Comment: Lovely...It worked..Thanks alot for your help Peter..Iam so happy

Comment: @user2075017 the best thanks here is that green tick) happy to help!

Comment: One more requirement..
I have the output generetaed the the path mentioned.

What should be done to get the output generated to the same locatino where excel presents

Comment: This: `strOutputFileName = xlBook.Path & "\" & xlSheet.Name & ".txt"` will save TXT to the same folder as original workbook.

Comment: yeah..this is fine i think the original path file needs to be changed to..and what should be used in place of this Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\bera02a\Desktop\Arun_TAT_Testing_orig_14022013.xls")

Comment: This should not be changed - here you specify which workbook to open.

Comment: Actually each time i move the excel to different location then the source path needs to be changed

Comment: @user2075017 Sorry, there's NO such function in VBA like "guess where is my workbook"))

Comment: ok...changing the path each time is the only option ?
I thought there would be something like this.path :(

Comment: @user2075017 If you run the code strictly FROM the workbook you should change - you may use `Set xlBook = xlApp.ThisWorkbook` - it will reference to the file from where macro is launched. The rest of code is fine. I suppose that's the only option.

Comment: ok..i wanna send the excel as an attachment here i am not getting the last workbook data..how can i attach so that u can have a look ?

Rest everything is fine..need to fix this for last workbook too

Comment: @user2075017 save your vba code with workbook and that's ok. If you have Excel 2007 or later - make sure you save it as Excel Macro-enabled Workbook, otherwise VBA won't be saved.

Comment: yeah..that is working for all the workbooks i donno why the last workbook is getting the data of the second workbook..i couldnt find any wrong in the code.just thought of providing that to u so that you can get a clear picture

Comment: Hi Peter ..I am stuck up with the only workbook :(
COuld you please help me in this ?